# December 18th 2022 updates to ubuntu 22.04 kill bluetooth support

Tags: upgrade, bluetooth, 22.04

I was watching a youtube video with my headset on today.
I decided to run updates in the background while I did.

mid video I stopped getting sound, checked bluetooth settings and I can't disconnect the headset, try turning off and back on bluetooth and now it refuses to turn back on, it sais no bluetooth found, plug in a dongle.

these updates killed bluetooth.

How do I fix this?

EDIT : so I've rebooted multiple times and can confirm the issue persists.

I also checked /var/log/history and this was the items for today:

```
Start-Date: 2022-12-18  09:23:47
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xserver-common:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.3, 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.5)
End-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:01

Start-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:04
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xwayland:amd64 (2:22.1.1-1ubuntu0.3, 2:22.1.1-1ubuntu0.4)
End-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:10

Start-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:15
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: tzdata:amd64 (2022f-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2022g-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:21

Start-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:24
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xserver-xephyr:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.3, 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.5)
End-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:31

Start-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:33
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python3-pil:amd64 (9.0.1-1build1, 9.0.1-1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:36

Start-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:38
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.3, 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.5)
End-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:46

Start-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:49
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.3, 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.5)
End-Date: 2022-12-18  09:24:56

Start-Date: 2022-12-18  11:11:33
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.134'
Upgrade: initramfs-tools-core:amd64 (0.140ubuntu13, 0.140ubuntu13.1), python3-tz:amd64 (2022.1-1, 2022.1-1ubuntu0.22.04.0), initramfs-tools-bin:amd64 (0.140ubuntu13, 0.140ubuntu13.1), brave-browser:amd64 (1.46.140, 1.46.144), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.2, 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.3), initramfs-tools:amd64 (0.140ubuntu13, 0.140ubuntu13.1), python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.2, 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.3)
End-Date: 2022-12-18  11:13:05
```

Comment: fixed the title

Comment: No sure if its related but after updating ubuntu today, my bluetooth no longer auto connects after a restart

Comment: Try an older kernel. Ubuntu keeps them around for some time, so it should still be listed in grub

Comment: switching kernels under ubuntu 22.04 is particularly broken, I tried this on a past install of ubuntu 22.04 over a wifi issue (which I found a workaround for that doesn't require kernel change in the end) a couple weeks ago. I haven't gotten it to work. even after forcing the install of one it refused to boot. i was forced to boot with the stock one.